# need to find shortest path between two nodes based on one of the node's property value -USING JAVA and 3.0.1 neo4j version

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Assume My Graph is having the below paths

```
      (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[CARRIES,77]-->(53)<--[CARRIES,76]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
      (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[BELONGS_TO,7]-->(1)<--[BELONGS_TO,6]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
      (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[BELONGS_TO,7]-->(55)<--[BELONGS_TO,61]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
      (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[CARRIES,77]-->(57)<--[CARRIES,75]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
```

Assume paths having the below mentioned properties

```
     (53) node has the properties--{Name:A}

     (1) node has properties--{Name:B}

     (55) node has properties--{Name:C}

     (57) node has properties-- {Name:D}
```

Assume If I call the shortestpath between nodes (3) and (2) , I am getting the below output when called the below mentioned method.

assume current Output is:

```
        (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[BELONGS_TO,7]-->(1)<--[BELONGS_TO,6]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
        (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[BELONGS_TO,7]-->(55)<--[BELONGS_TO,61]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
```

But My requirement is 1)It should filter the paths based on node property before calling the shortestpath api assume my filter is {Name:D} which is a property of (57) node mentioned above

Then My output should be as below when called shortespath method menntioned below as the below path having node (57) having property {Name:D} .

Expected Output with filter

```
          (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[CARRIES,77]-->(57)<--[CARRIES,75]--(7)--[IS_LOCATED_AT,8]-->(2)
```

I dont want to use cypher for this. Can anybody help me.

```
         public static Iterable<Path> shortestPath(Node sourceNode, Node destNode)
         {
            Integer depth=100;
            PathExpander<?> expander;
            List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
              if ( orderedRelTypes == null )
                {
                   expander = PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections();
                }
             else
               {
                  PathExpanderBuilder expanderBuilder =   PathExpanderBuilder.empty();

                  expanderBuilder = expanderBuilder

                  .add(MyRelationshipTypes.BELONGS_TO, Direction.BOTH)
                  .add(MyRelationshipTypes.CARRIES, Direction.BOTH)
                  .add(MyRelationshipTypes.IS_LOCATED_AT, Direction.BOTH);

                  expander = expanderBuilder.build();

                 }
              try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {


             PathFinder<Path> shortestPath = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(
               expander, depth == null ? 100 : depth.intValue());
               Iterable<Path> pathss = shortestPath.findAllPaths(sourceNode, destNode);

               for(Path path1:pathss){
               paths.add(path1);

        System.out.println("result::::"+paths);
              }

            tx.success();
           }
          return paths;
         }
   }
```

Comment: don't quite understand what the question really is here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to find the shortestpath between two nodes by applying predicate(based on Node property value filter ).can you give me the steps for this.can I acheive this with neo4j 3.0.1 java version.

Comment: The code looks fine so far. Maybe adding a failing unit test with some sample data would explain better why the above doesn't behave as you intend.

Comment: I have got these two shortest paths.But my requirement is I need to add filter to these paths also based on one or more node property values using java API. Is there way I can add filter to GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath api or you can give me the suggestions. PATH1:::: (3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[BELONGS_TO,7]-->(1)<--[BELONGS_TO,6]--(7)--[IS_LO‌​CATED_AT,8]-->(2)                                                                                PATH2:::(3)<--[IS_LOCATED_AT,9]--(8)--[CARRIES,68]-->(51)<--[CARRIES,67]--(7)--[IS_LOCAT‌​ED_AT,8]-->(2)

Comment: so a path is valid if each and every node along that path has the property with the defined value set? Or is the restriction that at least one node along that path needs to fulfill the criteria?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply ,Stefan , it is the restriction that at least one node along that path needs to fulfill the criteria .One more question is it possible to put filter  on Node before calling shortest path API? I mean it should filter the paths based on filter on node properties and then shortest path api should be called on the filtered paths. Is it possible.if yes suggestion please.

Comment: sefan, kindly comment

Comment: Use Cypher it's much easier, it will automatically pull in predicates into the shortest-path when possible.

Comment: Thanks Hunger for your reply,But our requirement is to use neo4j java api .not Cypher.

Comment: Hi Hunger, Could you please help.I have updated question with more details.Waiting for your response.Thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

If the restriction applies to at least one node along the path (and not to every node) the snippet above will not work. The strategy to apply here would be as follows:

1. use `shortestPath.findAllPaths` without filtering for the node property
2. filter the shortest paths you've found in 1) if any of those contains a node with the given property. If yes: done, otherwise:
3. use `GraphAlgoFactory.pathsWithLength()` and ask for paths of length+1 (where length is the length of the shortest paths from step 1)
4. check if any of paths with length+1 fulfills the criteria (see 2). If not go back to 3 with `length=length+1`

An alternative way would be using `GraphDatabaseService.bidirectionalTraversalDescription()` and apply the property check within the collision evaluator. But I consider this approach way more complex than the strategy sketched above.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.My understanding is property check can be done before calling shortestPath.findAllPaths() provided using GraphDatabaseService.bidirectionalTraversalDescription(). Since this is complex, Would you please publish the sample code if you have.

Comment: some examples are in the unit tests of Neo4j's source code: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/traversal/TestBidirectionalTraversal.java

Comment: what is the use of addNodeFilter method from PathExpanderBuilder class

Comment: we need to find the shortestpath between two nodes using node property filter using Neo4j 3.0.1 java version.

What I mean is shortestpath api should filter the paths based on node filter property internally and among the filtered paths , it should find the shortest path. Is this possible?If yes would you please give us github link or some suggetions. Once again,  Thank you for your help .

Comment: from your verbal description it's almost impossible to understand the problem. Provide some sample data - preferably by sharing a setup via http://console.neo4j.org/ - and also the expected result.

Comment: MATCH path = allshortestPaths((a:Place { Name: 'Mysore' })<-[*]
    ->(b:Place { Name: 'Bangalore' }))
WHERE ANY(x IN nodes(path) WHERE x.Type = "Geographic")
RETURN path.     Instead of cypher, I want to achive the same using neo4j java api.I am not able to achive this using nodeFilter used in the above program.Can you give some suggestions.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Could you please help.I have updated question with more details.Waiting for your response